# Remove username in emails or swap username for email

Tags: php, login, buddypress, user-registration

Is there anyway I can remove all instances of the username in all WP emails, or swap our the username for the email address?

I have some code in my `functions.php` file that removes the username from the registration and uses the email as the login, but it makes it so the username is randomly generated; that means all emails going out to the user that contain a username field will get *username: random-string-of-letters*, which I'm trying to remove/swap.

Below is code removing the username from registration:

```
add_action( 'bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'custom_validate_user_signup' );

function custom_validate_user_signup($result)
{
  unset($result['errors']->errors['user_name']);

  if(!empty($result['user_email']) && empty($result['errors']->errors['user_email']))
  {
    $result['user_name'] = md5($result['user_email']);
    $_POST['signup_username'] = $result['user_name'];
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is really close worthy. Is this about Buddypress alone or about WordPress? In other words: Can you remove Buddypress from the question?

Comment: @kaiser I guess if it's WP that requires the username you can remove BP from the question.

Comment: Then please do so. Unless one can replicate your problem without installing Buddypress or any other plugin, I will have to close that question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to take the `md5()` out of this line:

```
$result['user_name'] = md5($result['user_email']);
```

I'm not that familiar with buddy press but if `empty($result['errors']->errors['user_email'])` being true means a user was succesfully registered I'd use something like

```
wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'name' => $result['user_email'] ) );
```

Comment: Remove the code inside the if statement with `wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'name' => $result['user_email'] ) );`?

Comment: taking out the `md5()` worked, thanks a lot!